# applet not working in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

i am try to run applet in chrome but applet not running. i install java but than also not working. i check on http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1 link but it displays no java install but it running fine in firefox.

My chrome updated version is 18.0.1025.142m and I install java from http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp (latest version)

still it displays plugin out of date.

please help me.

Comment: Do you have jre installed for browser? I guess we call it as plugin. Check chrome plugins for JRE. If not there, you need to install it.

Comment: i install java from http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: in my firefox it working fine. and it displays properly installed.but in chrome not working.

Comment: Check chrome plugins. Some times versions might not be supported.

Comment: you are write in previous version of chrome it works fine but after update it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Type this into your chrome search bar

chrome://plugins/

Now enable java plugin

Problem solved !!